# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA in Java Application.  I am try to update my data in mysql, but i got this Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: last_updated_mdm_id of: com.avanir.mdm.app.model.hcp.MdmId [UPDATE com.avanir.mdm.app.model.hcp.MdmId e SET e.last_updated_mdm_id = :id where e.last_updated_mdm_id = :nextid]
```

How to fix this problem ? Thanks.

My code

```
 public static void updateMdmId(String lastUpdatedMdmId) throws IOException {

        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc").createEntityManager();
        String id = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(lastUpdatedMdmId) +1 );
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE MdmId e SET e.last_updated_mdm_id = :id" +
                " where e.last_updated_mdm_id = :nextid");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.setParameter("nextid", lastUpdatedMdmId);
        int rowsUpdated = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("entities Updated: " + rowsUpdated);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
```

desc table

```
mysql> desc mdm_id;
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| last_updated_mdm_id | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.64 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are trying to update the primary key of the table using the query. Instead you could take a different approach altogether.

1. Create a clone of the entity that you want to update.
2. Delete it from the table.
3. Update the entity and Insert it as a new entry into the table.

As per the [JPA Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) :

- Entity class must be annotated with the Entity annotation.
- Entity class must have a no-arg constructor.
- Entity class must not be final.
- Entity class must implement the Serializable interfaces. Entity class
  must have a unique, **immutable ID**

So in general I don't think Hibernate will allow you to change the primary key of a table with update statements.

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to change the primary key, and jpa won't let you to modify it. so one of the solutions is that persist it and delete the previous record.